# AsNoTracking() and Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a Linq query that fetches an entity and some of its navigation properties.

```
context.MyEntity
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(i=> i.Nav1)
    .Include(i=> i.Nav2)
    .Where(x=> x.Prop1==1)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

my question is:

Is the above query enough to not track `MyEntity` nor the navigation properties `NAv1`& `Nav2` or must I add `AsNoTracking` for each navigation property?

like this:

```
context.MyEntity
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(i=> i.Nav1)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(i=> i.Nav2)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x=> x.Prop1==1)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You only need `AsNoTracking` once per query so your 1st example is correct. I believe the second one will throw a run time exception (not sure which one).

Comment: If you chain multiple LINQ methods you always pass the returned sequence from the prior method to the following. So after `AsNoTracking` you have a query where the entities returned will not be cached

Comment: Both of the above comments are **WRONG**.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use AsNoTracking after you have completed all your query parameters but before you move the data into memory. In this example, you'll want:

```
context.MyEntity
    .Include(i=> i.Nav1)
    .Include(i=> i.Nav2)
    .Where(x=> x.Prop1==1)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Any child objects of the parent entity will not be tracked.

In .net core, consider using:

```
context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

This will disable the tracking behavior as a configuration rather than as a property of the query (note that the behavior will only apply to that context unless you add it to the context constructor).

Comment: Dangerous recommendation.  Since change tracking is enabled by default disabling this centrally is one of those things that could frustrate an entire team of people without them realizing what's affecting their work.  It's also natural to assume that when you make changes to object state they would be persisted when saved.  Disabling globally could result in creation of unintended orphaned records which is a problem that could hit production and not be discovered until it's too late.  Change tracking is the default for a reason.

Comment: @hunter the warning is well made, but there are certainly appropriate times for it's use, such as in long read-only operations or for read only applications. It's just important that the code matches the intent.

Comment: @Daniel Be aware that there are scenarios currently where `.AsNoTracking()` will be slower than `.AsTracking()`.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14366

Comment: Seems like this will not track both child objects and parent entity. Is there a way to track parent, but not child?

Comment: The question was how to do the query with NO tracking. If you want to track ONLY the parent, you should use this query and then re-add the parent to tracking. The easiest way I know is by doing this: `context.Entry(parentEntity).State = EntityState.Unchanged;`

Comment: There are many situations in application (especially in Web applications), which most of the time we get result and move to memory and go out of dbContext. In my opinion, despite warning from @HunterNelson, NoTracking will be helpful in many cases in Web App. I hope someone confirm or object my opinion if I'm wrong.

Comment: @FLICKER The warning is good to bear in mind. If your methods return EF entities and are inconsistent about whether they are tracked/untracked, callers of those methods could find it really frustrating. This is partly a weakness with EF, but it can be mitigated by (in descending order of preference): avoiding returning untracked entities, creating an `UntrackedEntity<T>` wrapper to explicitly show the return type, or creating separate `ReadonlyBLL` classes to segregate methods that return untracked entities.

Comment: @HunterNelson Years later I realize my answer should have been: that line of code does not disable change tracking globally, only for that context. Only adding it the constructor would make it persist outside that context. I've updated my answer with that clarification. That said, inconsistency in whether returned EF entities are tracked is still a risk that needs to be mitigated.

Comment: Also, maybe good to mention that `AsNoTracking()` can be used anywhere in the LINQ statement. It's not absolutely necessary to place it at the end. It always turns off tracking for an entire statement. The first part of the first comment above ("You only need AsNoTracking once per query so your 1st example is correct.") was correct.

Comment: @GertArnold Do you have a source for that, and is it true for both EF6 and EF Core? My (vague) recollection is that the location in the statement can produce some unexpected results if it is used before any of the query modifications, but if that's incorrect I can update my answer.

Comment: No, just experience. It's not hard to confirm it.