# How to unit test nested method using xunit in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

I have below scenario

```
public long Update(ExpenseViewModel updateModel, string einterpriseid)
{
    long internId;
    ExpenseReq expenseRequest = GetReqById(updateModel.Id);
    if (expenseRequest != null)
    {
        int DraftStatusID = GetStatusID("Draft");
        int PendingStatusID = GetStatusID("Pending Approval");
    }
 }

 public ExpenseReq GetReqById(int id)
 {
    return _db.ExpRequest
            .Include(x => x.Profile).AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.ExpReqStatus).AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.AdditionalDetails)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.ExpenseReqTravelDetails).AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.AddDetail)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.ExpRejReason).AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.AdditionalDetails)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.ExpenseTypes).AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.AdditionalDetails)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.ExpReqApprover).AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.Comp).AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

When I am performing unit test on `Update` the `GetReqById` function is always returning me `null` because of which the if condition is not getting satisfied and inside if condition line coverage is not happening. I want to get the code coverage inside if condition. How to write unit test for it?
I have tried below:

```
[Fact]
public void Should_Update()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<dbContextobj>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "fakedb").Options;

    using (var context = new dbContextobj(options))
    { 
        var controller = new ExpenseRequestService(context);
        var result = controller.Update(expenseRequestUpdateViewModel, "test");
        Assert.Equal(0, result);
    }
}
```

This works fine but the `GetReqById` is not getting covered. Please help me with some sample code.

Thank you.

[image: debug]

Comment: If you move `GetReqById` into another class and interface, then inject that interface into your object's constructor, then your test code can "Mock" that interface to make that method call return whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the problem here is the code is already running in production and now making any changes in existing code will go for thorough testing and required approvals. so i dont want to make any changes in existing and without making any change i want to perform unit test.

Comment: Ur using `UseInMemoryDatabase` means that every time u run the project it will create new data as far as i know. So if u really wenting to test the unit of the code u do need to Mock the return of the database otherwise you would be testing more then you should. Keep in mind that unit tests focus on testing the method and not your dependencies.

Comment: Not related to the question, but something I noticed in the source.  I don't believe you should use `AsNoTracking()` on each `Include`.  `AsNoTracking()` will apply to the parent entity and all child entities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002540/asnotracking-and-include

Comment: While I understand your hesitance to make changes that aren't strictly necessary for the tests you need to add, it's a red flag to me when developers are afraid to refactor code. Just sayin'.

Comment: @PeterRiesz i have updated the code please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup the database with the required data:

```csharp
[Fact]
public void Should_Update()
{
    // Assign
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<dbContextobj>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "fakedb").Options;
    using var context = new dbContextobj(options);
    context.ExpenseReq.Add(new ExpenseReq { Id = "test" })
    context.SaveChanges();

    var controller = new ExpenseRequestService(context);

    // Act
    var result = controller.Update(expenseRequestUpdateViewModel, "test");

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(0, result);
}
```

However many will comment that this is not technically a **unit** test due to the use of the `InMemoryDatabase`.

Comment: Hi @peter Riesz , I have already tried the above code but still facing the same. i have added a screenshot for the reference in my question part please have a look . I need this GetReqById should return me some object so that the if condition pass so that the line code coverage  will increase.

Comment: Sorry @ManishGupta its working for me.  I did a few experiments to see if it would fail if the `Id` used `ValueGenerators` or if the `Includes` where 1-1 required relationships but it still returned the queried entity.

Comment: You are correct . Its working but only if I keep the first table for example :- return _db.ExpRequest.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();  .. if I am Including all other tables then the query is returning null. not sure why.. though I am adding data for others table.

Comment: Its worked. just mapping of the correct data is required as there is a FK relationship. Thanks a lot.